# Use MPI IO to append array to an existing file

Tags: io, fortran, mpi

When running a parallel program, we might need to write result to files for post-processing. These files are often with specific format, for example: title (characters/strings) + binary array (real/float). This can be done with 2 steps: 1. use master processor to create a new file and write title. 2. use MPI IO to append the array data to this file. I tried to use MPI_MODE_APPEND as amod in MPI_FILE_OPEN to append data to the existing file, but this step fails. The FORTRAN code is (I tried MPI_MODE_APPEND only and MPI_MODE_APPEND+MPI_MODE_WRONLY)

```
 call MPI_File_open(comm, filename, MPI_MODE_APPEND+MPI_MODE_WRONLY, &
                 MPI_INFO_NULL, fh, ierr)
```

Also, the new result overwrites the old data. How should I correct this statement? Many thanks.

Comment: How is the complete code? Do you set the views using the same procedures as in my testmpi.f90 in PoisFFT? Show the code also for others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vladimir for this reminder. I think I make it. The original code snippet was

```
 integer (kind=MPI_OFFSET_KIND) :: disp = 0
 integer :: n1, n2, n3
 double precision, dimension(0:n1+1,0:n2+1,0:n3+1) :: iodata
 integer, dimension(ndim) :: arraysize, arraystart
 integer, dimension(ndim) :: arraygsize, arraysubsize

   ...

  call MPI_Type_create_subarray(ndim, arraygsize, arraysubsize, arraystart, &
                                MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                                filetype, ierr)

  call MPI_Type_commit(filetype, ierr)


  arraystart(:) = 1

  call MPI_Type_create_subarray(ndim, arraysize, arraysubsize, arraystart, &
                                MPI_ORDER_FORTRAN, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                                mpi_subarray, ierr)

  call MPI_Type_commit(mpi_subarray, ierr)


  call MPI_File_open(cartcomm, filename,    MPI_MODE_APPEND+MPI_MODE_WRONLY, &
                     MPI_INFO_NULL, fh, ierr)

  call MPI_File_set_view(fh, disp, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, filetype, 'native', &
                         MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr)

  call MPI_File_write_all(fh, iodata, 1, mpi_subarray, status, ierr)
```

Indeed, I used the correct mode: MPI_MODE_APPEND+MPI_MODE_WRONLY. However, I did not set the offset/displacement and append the parallel data with 0 displacement, which means overwrite the file.

I should add another statement after MPI_FILE_OPEN which is

```
call MPI_FILE_GET_POSITION(fh, disp, ierr)
```

It gets the current position with argument disp. disp gives the correct position for appended data to the existing file.